# Online - User able to upload file with anonymous share link

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, share, anonymous-access

I'm facing this issue on my SharePoint Online.

I've shared a folder with an anonymous link where I disabled edit. In this scenario I don't want to let anonymous users to upload files or create folders.

Trying the anonymous link I've seen that I'm able to upload new files or create folders. Correctly, I can not delete files or folder I create.

Is it possible to prevent file upload o folder creation by guest/anonymous users?

Answer (score 0):

I would break inheritance of permissions on the folder, then assign anonymous users "Read" permission only for that folder and its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to SharePoint admin center-> Policies-> Sharing , in the File and folder links section, choose view permission for "These links can give these permissions:". Like this:

[image]